# ASP.NET MVC 3 FormsAuthentication ReturnURL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Forms Authentication in my MVC 3 app and having a problem with my return URL.

When I mark an action `<Authorize>` on the Home controller, it redirects to the login page and works, but the return URL is then `/`, so when it redirects, it is redirecting to the root of the the current URL `Authorize`.

So the URL's are like this:

http://localhost/ - Controller = Home - Action = Index

http://localhost/Authentication/LogOn

I end up with this: http://localhost/Authentication/LogOn?ReturnURL=~%2F, I need to get back to http://localhost/

Help!! :)

Comment: what is your http://localhost/ default route ?

Comment: @Nazar - `routes.MapRoute( _
            "Default", _
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your Account controllers LogOn action to something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
```

Comment: The FormsAuthentication handles the routing I believe.

Comment: I figured it out, I was using RedirectToAction, should have been using just Redirect. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

http://localhost/Authentication/LogOn?ReturnURL=~%2F,
it means home url is duplicated